# Array ordering on nth item

Tags: php

Say I have an array,

```
array('one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','nine','ten');
```

And I want to order on every third item so that now I get:

```
array('one','five','nine','two','six','ten','three','seven','x','four','eight','x');
```

Basically, the ultimate goal is to resort for floats to line up top to bottom instead of left to right. I know the other methods (either dropping IE9--, monkey around with SCSS, or using javascript). Using PHP is the lowest resource hit other than losing older IE 9 support, so let's just focus on the PHP.

Now, I can see I need to pad the original array to a multiple of 3, but I can't think of a way to get the ordering I need without three nested loops and modulus expressions.

The array values are placeholders, so don't get hung up on those.

Comment: I read that 5 times and still can't discern what you want to do...

Comment: @AbraCadaver His wording is bad... I think he meant that he wants to divide the original array into 3 groups, then transpose/zip them and flatten the array, NOT "order on every third item"

Comment: Sorry about the wording, but I wanted array 1 to pop out as array 2 is all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution, the output is in `$output`.

```
// Input
$data = array('one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','nine','ten');
$groups = 3;

// Calculations
$num_per_group = ceil(count($data) / $groups);
$final_size = $groups * $num_per_group;         // Multiple of $groups
$data = array_pad($data, $final_size, "x");     // Pad to $final_size

$output = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $num_per_group; $i++) {       // Outer loop, by # per group
    for ($j = 0; $j < $groups; $j++) {          // Inner loop, by # of groups
        $output[] = $data[$j * $num_per_group + $i];
    }
}
```

Output:

```
php > var_dump($output);
array(12) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "one"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "five"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "nine"
  [3]=>
  string(3) "two"
  [4]=>
  string(3) "six"
  [5]=>
  string(3) "ten"
  [6]=>
  string(5) "three"
  [7]=>
  string(5) "seven"
  [8]=>
  string(1) "x"
  [9]=>
  string(4) "four"
  [10]=>
  string(5) "eight"
  [11]=>
  string(1) "x"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = array('one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','nine','ten');

// prepare
$n = 0;                 // counter
$x = array();           // storage
$f = ceil(count($a)/3); // we need a number of arrays so that each 
                        // one has to hold no more than three entries

// distribute
foreach ($a as $entry) {
    $i = $n++ % $f;     // calculate into which array to drop the entry
    $x[$i][] = $entry;  // drop it
}

// collect it
$z = array();
for ($i = 0; $i<$f; $i++) {
        if (count($x[$i])<count($x[0])) $x[$i][] = 'x'; // pad it if too short
        $z = array_merge($z, $x[$i]);
}
```

`$a` contains the input and `$z` the output string.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to sort the array. I sometimes solved it this way:

```
$col  = 0;
$cols = 3;

foreach($array as $number){

 $col++;
 if($col == 1){
  echo '<tr>'
 }

 echo '<td>'.$number.'</td>';

 if($col == $cols){
  echo '</tr>'
  $col = 0;
 }

}
```

Advances: You only need one loop and you can output all code you like between the cols amd rows.

Answer (score 0):

A more refined solution using just a single loop in a neat function:

```
function pad_and_transpose_columns($data, $groups) {
    $num_per_group = ceil(count($data) / $groups);
    $final_size = $groups * $num_per_group;         // Multiple of $groups
    $data = array_pad($data, $final_size, "x");     // Pad to $final_size

    $output = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $final_size; $i++) {
        $output[] = $data[($i * $num_per_group + floor($i / $groups)) % 12];
    }
    return $output;
}

$data = array('one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','nine','ten');
$output = pad_and_transpose_columns($data, 3);
// array('one','five','nine','two','six','ten','three','seven','x','four','eight','x');
```